# Examples of ReactJs desktop-like component libraries

Tags: reactjs

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I've just started developing desktop applications with the [Electron.js](https://electronjs.org/) framework but the apps I develop with it do not really look like desktop apps. Please could you provide links to ReactJS desktop-like components libraries? something like [React Desktop](http://reactdesktop.js.org).

Comment: Maybe Ant Design (https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce)?

Comment: https://react95.github.io/React95/ looks very desktopy :trollface: